# Nagios Glabal event handler

Tags: nagios, network-monitoring

what's the use case of global event handler in nagios and how can I configure it to send the information to my otherserver where I have to perform some action based on the information sent (like servicestate, service attempt etc.,)

Specifically, I just need a way to invoke a script, whenever any service goes off or any host dies irrespective of whatever it is

Answer (score 0):

You define the event handler in the commands.cfg file in Nagios.  Adding Nagios MACROS' as arguments to pass to the event handler.  Then add the event handler to your default template (often generic-service), so that everything uses it. This is all explained in great detail in the Nagios Core documentation.  Then the event handler script/program is ran AFTER each event.